# micronaut build native image, but can not work

Tags: micronaut, graalvm

I use graalvm 22.2.0 ce, java 17, mvn 3.8.6 to build a micronaut project to native image.

I use this command: `mvn package -Dpackaging=native-image`

and I get the native image file successfully.

but I use `./target/native-image-file` command to execute, it report like this:

```
07:51:29.345 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.undertow.Undertow]

Message: io.undertow.util.FastConcurrentDirectDeque.<init>()
Path Taken: new UndertowServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,Undertow undertow) --> new UndertowServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,[Undertow undertow]) --> Undertow.undertowServer([Builder builder])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type  [io.undertow.Undertow]

Message: io.undertow.util.FastConcurrentDirectDeque.<init>()
Path Taken: new UndertowServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,Undertow undertow) --> new UndertowServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext,ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration,[Undertow undertow]) --> Undertow.undertowServer([Builder builder])
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2367)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
        at io.micronaut.servlet.undertow.$UndertowFactory$UndertowServer1$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1617)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractBeanResolutionContext.getBean(AbstractBeanResolutionContext.java:66)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:2065)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1297)
        at io.micronaut.servlet.undertow.$UndertowServer$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2305)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2251)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:3016)
        at io.micronaut.context.SingletonScope.getOrCreate(SingletonScope.java:80)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findOrCreateSingletonBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2918)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2879)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2800)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1680)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1655)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:878)
        at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.findBean(BeanLocator.java:291)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:77)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:323)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:309)
        at com.example.Application.main(Application.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.undertow.util.FastConcurrentDirectDeque.<init>()
        at io.undertow.util.ConcurrentDirectDeque.<clinit>(ConcurrentDirectDeque.java:45)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.cache.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.<init>(ServletPathMatches.java:82)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentImpl.<init>(DeploymentImpl.java:95)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:151)
        at io.micronaut.servlet.undertow.UndertowFactory.undertowBuilder(UndertowFactory.java:97)
        at io.micronaut.servlet.undertow.$UndertowFactory$UndertowBuilder0$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveByBeanFactory(DefaultBeanContext.java:2354)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

here is my maven xml dependencies, I just use undertow server, not use netty server.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>${packaging}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <jdk.version>17</jdk.version>
        <release.version>17</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>3.6.3</micronaut.version>
        <micronaut.runtime>undertow</micronaut.runtime>
        <exec.mainClass>com.example.Application</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-undertow</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.truffle/truffle-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.graalvm.truffle</groupId>
            <artifactId>truffle-api</artifactId>
            <version>22.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
            <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.build</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
                    <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

                    <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                        <path>
                            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                            <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
                            <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.example</arg>
                        <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=micronaut-demo</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know how should fix this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which version of `io.undertow.util.FastConcurrentDirectDeque` are you using?

Comment: I just use undertow http server in pom.xml. I add my pom file content in question.

Comment: Is your project using `io.undertow:undertow-core:2.2.18.Final` at runtime?

Comment: Please report an issue here https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-servlet/issues